# Can't install inspec due to a sha256 error (Cannot find type)

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, inspec

I am trying to install inspec in powershell and during the install I am receiving an error.

*Cannot find type [Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng]:  verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.*

The current version of powershell is 7.

The install command being used is.

*. { iwr -useb https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.ps1 } | iex; install -project inspec*

It installs ok on the windows powershell version 5.1 but it doesn't on the downloaded and installed version of powershell 7.4.1

I have tried hashing something using sha256 and it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [`SHA256Cng` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256cng?view=netframework-4.8.1) only exists .NET Framework and PowerShell 7+ uses .NET, if you wanted to make it work, the function having a reference to that class is `Get-SHA256Converter` and you could change it to this to make it compatible with both versions:

```bash
function Get-SHA256Converter {
    if ($IsCoreCLR) {
        return [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
    }

    if ((Is-FIPS) -ge 1) {
        return [Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng]::new()
    }

    [Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed]::new()
}
```

Comment: Can you re post?  The formatting is all messed up.

Comment: @Fr0ntSight im not sure what you mean by formatting all messed up. looks fine on my side